# Finding ids from 2nd table that have a match for all the records

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have two tables. How can I select distinct bookstore which includes all authors?

table1:

```
author
1
2
3
```

table2:

```
bookstore  author
A             1
A             2
A             3
B             1
B             2
```

Expected result:

```
bookstore
A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to handle this.  This answer uses an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables.  This join will remove any entries from `table2` which have non matching authors.  Then, we aggregate over each bookstore and check to make sure that we are left with every author from `table1`.

```
SELECT t2.bookstore
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.author = t2.author
GROUP BY t2.bookstore
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.author) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1)
```

Note that I assume that each author only appears once in `table1`.  If there could be duplicates there too, then you should count authors using this subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT author) FROM table1
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do the aggregation at table2 to find out how many authors do each bookstore covers. Then finally a filtering condition (HAVING) to select the entries which covers every authors.

```
    SELECT [bookstore]
      FROM [dbo].[table2]
  GROUP BY [bookstore]
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [author]) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [author]) FROM [dbo].[table1])
```

Comment: This query has a potential problem, because a given bookstore in `table2` might have authors which do not match anything in `table1`.  If so, then your count of authors would be skewed.